# tikzplotlib adds extra lines to plot that do not exist

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, tikz

When using [tikzplotlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tikzplotlib/), some random lines that don't exist in my plot appear. This is consistently a thing.

**Original as seen in Python using matplotlib.pyplot**
[image]

**Output after compiling from tikzplotlib into LaTeX**
[image]

Ignore the sizing difference as one is in LaTeX and one is blown up in Python. Anyways, notice the gray lines running along the zeros of both axis? Why does this happen when it is not showing in the PyPlot?

Comment: A similar problem has been raised: https://github.com/nschloe/matplotlib2tikz/issues/196

Comment: Sounds like a bug in tikzplotlib. You're much better off reporting it there than here.